# Android reverse geocoding getLocality returns often null

Tags: android, reverse-geocoding

I am using Android Geocoding to get the current city with `Address.getLocality()`. It has worked fine, until just recently it appears to often return null for the locality.

Here is an example:

```
try {
    Geocoder c = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    double lat = 51.481;
    double lon = 0.0;
    List<Address> l = c.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 5);
    for (Address a: l) {
        Log.i("GeocoderTest", "Locality " + a.getLocality() + " (" + a + ")");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("GeocoderTest", "", e);
}
```

This now logs the following message for the first returned address:

> Locality null (Address[addressLines=[0:"14-18 Park Vista",1:"London
>   Borough of Greenwich, London
>   SE10",2:"UK"],feature=,admin=null,sub-admin=null,locality=null,thoroughfare=Park
>   Vista,postalCode=null,countryCode=GB,countryName=United
>   Kingdom,hasLatitude=true,latitude=51.4819069,hasLongitude=true,longitude=-6.327E-4,phone=null,url=null,extras=null])

Some locations do return the city in the locality, while a location next to it does not.

So it did work just fine before, actually I had not seen a null locality before. So I guess something must have changed in Google's geocoding service. Any idea what is going on, and is this situation permanent? If yes, what would be the best way to determine the city from a location?

Answer (score 12):

I noticed, that very often getLocality() returns null for the first address in the list, returned by Geocoder.
On the other hand correct city name stays at Locality of a next Address.
So I am using this workaround and it works well for big cities:

```
 private String getCityNameByCoordinates(double lat, double lon) throws IOException {
    List<Address> addresses = mGeocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 10);
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        for (Address adr : addresses) {
            if (adr.getLocality() != null && adr.getLocality().length() > 0) {
                return adr.getLocality();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. This is better than having null value :)

Comment: Thanks for the update ! @Leo Droidcoder have u ever seen this to fail too ? I mean all the addresses fail ?

Comment: Can fail... It is happens with me

Comment: The code stops at `List<Address> addresses = mGeocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 10);` for me. What is the problem?

Answer (score 7):

Now I live in Canada, Ontario, Hamilton (Hamilton is my city, Ontario is the province)

I noticed that `getLocality()` returns null, and `getAdminArea()` returns Ontario, and `getSubLocality()` returns Hamilton. ch

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin I have done something like this, given the address `a`

```kotlin
var place = a.locality
if (place == null) place = a.subLocality
if (place == null) place = a.subAdminArea
if (place == null) place = a.adminArea
```

It works even for remote places

Comment: Instead you can also use `a.locality ?: a.subLocality ?: a.subAdminArea ?: a.adminArea`

Answer (score 0):

Using `getSubAdminArea()` worked fine for me.