# Getting sub locality null for some lat long?

Tags: android, gps, location, android-gps

Below is my code, I am getting null subLocality always ....

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses  = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude, 1);

String suburb = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
String zip = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();

Log.e("Log for data",""+suburb+" "+state+" "+zip+" "+country);
```

Below is my response;

```
null Gujarat 380006 India
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android reverse geocoding getLocality returns often null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661857/android-reverse-geocoding-getlocality-returns-often-null)

Comment: Yes, Geocoder makes issue sometimes *(I faced it in past, for some OEM it was always null)*. As an alternative solution, I migrated to **following API** as solution for *Geo-Coding* : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#reverse.

Comment: Hello @JeelVankhede ... How can I find subloaclity name from this webservice. In this big response which parameter I have to take?

Comment: You can determine it from `"types"` in that response if you've observed it closely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Geocoder API** will return the values depending on `lat` `long`, if the `API` database doesn't have these values exemple : `subLocality` then it will return `null` only, in my knowledge there's nothing you can do about it. You have to handle these cases gracefully so your app don't crash.

Handling these cases includes you have to put a check using `if` condition is that particular value is `null` or it has some value, because if you use any of the value somewhere in code without checking and if that value is `null` then app might crash whenever that particular value comes `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem which was solved by increasing the number of results which you request from Geocoder API.

Try increasing it to 10

```
List<Address> addresses  = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude, 10);
```

Then if your sub-locality is null with the `first` result, try search in the rest of them for the same

Comment: This can increase very memory usage or not? In the level of this can to cause lag on my application.

Comment: By example, previously i was using 1 max result and i up to 10, it is can that's to cause delay?